# Conditional Formatting without Excel GUI

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an automated report where'd I'd like to add conditional formatting to some cells.  Unfortunately, the only way to do this seems to be manually.

Does anyone know of a workflow to add conditional formatting only within a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add via `FormatConditions`

E.g. Red bg colour for values > 3

```
With Range("a1:a10").FormatConditions.Add( _
    XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, _
    XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater, _
    "=3")

    .SetFirstPriority
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the macro recorder does a decent job of helping with the properties and commands needed.  You have to do the normal cleanup, but it's a good starting place.